# How to calculate/estimate the contamination rate of ultra pure water (UPW) in the presence of metals?

Tags: redox, water

Metals are known to release ions into [ultra pure water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrapure_water). Do any equations or empirical data sets exist for estimating the rate of contamination with different metals? I don't need a specific solution; I just need better vocabulary in this topic to further research.

For example say we have 1 liter of >18.18 MΩ·cm ultra pure water. We expose this water to 1 cm^2 area of polished pure titanium metal for 100 hours at [STP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_temperature_and_pressure). What is the final resistivity or number of titanium ions in solution? (Feel free to make up a different scenario and assumptions if needed; I just need a starting point)

Comment: Hard to see how this could be answered. A piece of flat titanium (or other metal) exposed to still water is not serving as an electrode. But if it is used for, e.g., conductivity measurements, then the situation is different because various processes are happening at the (now) electrode’s surface. Maybe the still water and non-electrode case would set a lower contamination limit?

Comment: This is true. If I could just get a non-active baseline that would be of value. Sampling doesn't need to be continuous so the sensor would only need to run for say 10 milliseconds every 10 minutes or something like that. Just not sure where to begin.

Comment: Have you searched *contactless* conductivity methods? I don't know how sensitive it is to pure water but is has been used and shown chromatography sensors.

Comment: You could start with this (see Table 1, and the references on which it is based), then use Google Scholar to check all the (more modern) papers that have cited this paper:  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ac60301a006?casa_token=W2ipNRS3VLUAAAAA:efmus8wqfiDQQ9HT0DUfqU6MWrVKjUrKJJ-9JeVx0n-tCwSeU8pbu_bmsNh3Jz0fDg4OzVlJ7zjU3JI  , namely https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=1829773286810311078&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en .  You could also check Millipore's website.

Comment: @theorist, Thanks for the article link! This is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

While it is claimed that "Metals are known to release ions into ultra pure water", in my understanding, even pure water has some, albeit low amounts, of dissolved oxygen, for example, as noted in this [previously cited source](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ac60301a006?casa_token=W2ipNRS3VLUAAAAA:efmus8wqfiDQQ9HT0DUfqU6MWrVKjUrKJJ-9JeVx0n-tCwSeU8pbu_bmsNh3Jz0fDg4OzVlJ7zjU3JI).

Now, select metals (especially, for example, Cu, Fe,..) will undergo an [oxidation-reduction reaction](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/04._Reactions_in_Aqueous_Solution/4.4%3A_Oxidation-Reduction_Reactions) introducing metal ions and consuming O2 along with H+ (from the water or as further provided by say a CO2 presence from air contact).

Further, more than one metal presence can augment the process in a so-called  Galvano-assisted redox (see, for example, this 2020 work, ["Kinetic pathways of iron electrode transformations in Galvano-Fenton process: A mechanistic investigation of in-situ catalyst formation and regeneration"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1876107020303230)).

So, exactly how one separates out the alluded to chemistry and possible multi-metal contribution to the reputed metal ion formation in actually not precisely ultra pure water, and ascribe a direct singular metal direct process, is unclear/difficult, in my opinion.

So, as to your request "Feel free to make up a different scenario and assumptions if needed", removing oxygen is one of my key concerns along with using a pure metal source (not an alloy).

Comment: Excellent! That makes sense that there must be some reactions to create the metal ions in solution. Since calculation is not an option here; is it fair to say that, in a qualitative sense, a metal lower on the reactivity series would contaminate ultrapure water less than a metal higher on the reactivity series? With platinum contaminating the least?

Answer (score 1):

A pure metal immersed in pure water establishes a potential with the liquid.  Current understanding is that ions migrate into the water and electrons accumulate on the metal. If[when] the electrons react corrosion ensues. A potential would be developed against a reference electrode say a hydrogen electrode that should give an idea of the metal ion concentration. How this potential is to be measured accurately I have no idea except possibly as a limiting process.  Since different metals have very different potentials at reasonable concentrations it seems reasonable that the ionization process would differ for each. These thoughts do not require a reaction rather this process is what causes reactions.  For ions to accumulate in the solution the electrons must react with either water or the low concentration of H3O+ ions[corrosion].

Comment: Interesting, I will have to do some more research to understand. I present you with the same question though. Is it fair to say that, in a qualitative sense, a metal lower on the reactivity series would contaminate ultrapure water less than a metal higher on the reactivity series? With platinum contaminating the least?